# Input Text File into Excel Form

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a text file that contains anywhere from 30 lines to 1000 lines of data in there with each line containing anywhere from 10 to 200 characters. I'm trying to input this data into a text box on a user form when it initializes.

Code that I'm using now...

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim TextFile As Integer
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileContent As String

    FilePath = "C:\PATH\MyText.txt"

    TextFile = FreeFile

    Open FilePath For Input As TextFile

    FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)

    'MsgBox FileContent
    UserForm1.TextBox1 = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)

    Close TextFile

End Sub
```

It works fine when I try outputting the data to a MsgBox (however doesn't show ALL data), but when I try to output it to the TextBox I get the error...

> Run-time error '62':
>
> Input past end of file

I'm guessing it's not ready the `EOF` flag here... How would I go about doing this? Maybe it's because the input file is too large?

Any ideas or suggestions would be great!

Comment: @braX `LOF`, no. But `Input`-ing twice the file size would.

Comment: Well my original idea was to have the user input data into the TextBox and then it would save to the spreadsheet however it was exceeding it's cells limit. So I thought if I stored it in a text file instead it might solve my issue but it seems as though that I think I'm still having the same issue here... This text file I'm using is for testing purposes right now until I find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Input` moves the "pointer" as it reads the file.

You read the entire file here:

```
FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
```

Then once again here:

```
UserForm1.TextBox1 = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
```

But by then `FileContent` already has your entire content, and file handle#`TextFile` is already at EOF. So when you try to input again, you're *inputting past the end of the file*.

Just close the file immediately after reading it, and then do `UserForm1.TextBox1 = FileContent`.

No need to [try to] read the file twice: you *did* read the whole contents into `FileContent`. The reason why a `MsgBox` truncates it is because, well, a `MsgBox` (just like a cell) isn't made for this, and has a maximum content length. `TextBox1` should be able to handle it (unless you gave it a `MaxLength` value).

Comment: Simple mistake and your suggestion fixed it perfectly! One last question for you, is there a limit for characters in the TextBox? That's the only thing that has me a little worried; I've tried Googling it and all that came up were limits to cells and nothing related to forms... even when I search exclusively for forms. Also, very well explained, much appreciated

Comment: @Maldred From quick experimenting with `Me.TextBox1.Text = String(9999999, "A")` I think it's safe to assume the upper limit would be whatever the maximum length of a `String` is. I get "out of string space" with `String((2 ^ 31 - 1), "A")` (that would be a `Long` integer's max value), but that's likely just a limitation of the `String` function - by concatenating them I got over 3 million characters into it, so I'm pretty sure you can fit everything you need in there.

Comment: Perfect, that makes me feel at ease... Appreciate all your help sir

Comment: @Mat'sMug, appreciated your helpful hints to textbox lengths (apparently not restricted by the limitation of the `String` function)